# About the withCmd command of docker-java

Tags: java, docker-java

I want to ask how I use the withCmd method as follows:

```
commands = new String[]{"echo","test:111 | chpasswd"};
ExecCreateCmdResponse execCreateCmdResponse = dockerClient.execCreateCmd("b6b571d5469a")
       .withCmd(commands).withAttachStdout(true).withAttachStderr(true).exec();
```

I am changing the user password!
But it actually becomes the output string
Just like when I execute  `echo "test:111 | chpasswd"` under linux
How can I make it execute the command`echo test:111 | chpasswd`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try with a shell command

```
.withCmd("sh", "-c", "echo 'test:111' | chpasswd")
```